# How to set DMM4040 multimeter into remote mode?

Tags: labview

I have developed a labview program to set DMM4040 series multimeter into remote mode and it is not working. But when I did the same thing by NI-MAX It works fine.

I don't understand what is the problem with this code.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to show us the code first.

Are you using the instrument driver from the NI IDNet (Instrument Driver Network)?

If not, I strongly suggest you start with the driver, which for your instrument can be found here:

http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=16513